# How to loading/create a spi kernel module which controls a shift register?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, spi

Hej,

I would like to access on my custom board a shift register which is connected via SPI. When loading my kernel module I got the error that spi_busnum_to_master had failed.

My kernel module is a character device, which writes into the shift register + toggles a pin. The user can write into and read from this device. The module translates the input and sends some bytes via spi.

After checking I found out that it is possible to create an SPI Slave device. My code for doing it:

```
int helper_init_spi(void) {
    int ret;
    struct spi_master *master;

    struct spi_board_info spi_device_info = {
        .modalias = "mySPIslave",
        .max_speed_hz = 1000000, //speed your device (slave) can handle
        .bus_num = 0,
        .chip_select = 0,
        .mode = 3, // 3 wire
    };

    // get the spi master
    master = spi_busnum_to_master(spi_device_info.bus_num);
    if( !master ){
        printk(KERN_ALERT "%s: spi bus master (spi%i) not found\n", "myModule", spi_device_info.bus_num);
        return -ENODEV;
    }

    // create a new slave device, given the master and device info
    gMyDev = spi_new_device( master, &spi_device_info );
    if(!gMyDev) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "%s: failed to create the %s spi slave\n", "myModule", spi_device_info.modalias);
        return -ENODEV;
    }

    // set 8Bit mode
    gpESAledMatrix->bits_per_word = 8;

    // setup
    ret = spi_setup(gMyDev);
    if( ret ){
        printk(KERN_ALERT "%s: failed to setup spi slave\n", "myModule");
        spi_unregister_device(gpESAledMatrix);
        gpESAledMatrix = NULL;
        return -ENODEV;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

At "spi_busnum_to_master" my code fails. I was checking the kernel for the spi buses (via dmesg):

```
[    2.870000] atmel_spi f0004000.spi: version: 0x213
[    2.870000] atmel_spi f0004000.spi: Using dma0chan3 (tx) and dma0chan4 (rx) for DMA transfers
[    2.880000] atmel_spi f0004000.spi: Atmel SPI Controller at 0xf0004000 (irq 25)
[    3.090000] atmel_spi f8008000.spi: version: 0x213
[    3.100000] atmel_spi f8008000.spi: Using dma1chan0 (tx) and dma1chan1 (rx) for DMA transfers
[    3.100000] atmel_spi f8008000.spi: Atmel SPI Controller at 0xf8008000 (irq 30)
[    3.110000] m25p80 spi32765.0: s25fl164k (8192 Kbytes)
```

For me it looks like that the two spi-buses are initialized properly. But when checking "/dev/" there are no spi-masters.

```
root@sama5d3xek:/# find . -name *spi*
./sys/bus/spi
./sys/bus/spi/devices/spi32765.0
./sys/bus/spi/drivers/m25p80/spi32765.0
./sys/bus/spi/drivers/spidev
./sys/bus/platform/devices/f0004000.spi
./sys/bus/platform/devices/f8008000.spi
./sys/bus/platform/drivers/atmel_spi
./sys/bus/platform/drivers/atmel_spi/f0004000.spi
./sys/bus/platform/drivers/atmel_spi/f8008000.spi
./sys/bus/platform/drivers/atmel_qspi
./sys/bus/platform/drivers/spi_gpio
./sys/devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/f0004000.spi
./sys/devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/f0004000.spi/spi_master
./sys/devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/f0004000.spi/spi_master/spi32766
./sys/devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/f0004000.spi/spi_master/spi32766/statistics/spi_sync_immediate
./sys/devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/f0004000.spi/spi_master/spi32766/statistics/spi_sync
./sys/devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/f0004000.spi/spi_master/spi32766/statistics/spi_async
./sys/devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/f8008000.spi
./sys/devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/f8008000.spi/spi_master
./sys/devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/f8008000.spi/spi_master/spi32765
./sys/devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/f8008000.spi/spi_master/spi32765/statistics/spi_sync_immediate
./sys/devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/f8008000.spi/spi_master/spi32765/statistics/spi_sync
./sys/devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/f8008000.spi/spi_master/spi32765/statistics/spi_async
./sys/devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/f8008000.spi/spi_master/spi32765/spi32765.0
./sys/devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/f8008000.spi/spi_master/spi32765/spi32765.0/statistics/spi_sync_immediate
./sys/devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/f8008000.spi/spi_master/spi32765/spi32765.0/statistics/spi_sync
./sys/devices/soc0/ahb/ahb:apb/f8008000.spi/spi_master/spi32765/spi32765.0/statistics/spi_async
./sys/class/spi_master
./sys/class/spi_master/spi32765
./sys/class/spi_master/spi32766
./sys/class/spidev
./sys/firmware/devicetree/base/ahb/apb/pmc@fffffc00/periphck/spi0_clk
./sys/firmware/devicetree/base/ahb/apb/pmc@fffffc00/periphck/spi1_clk
./sys/firmware/devicetree/base/ahb/apb/pinctrl@fffff200/spi0
./sys/firmware/devicetree/base/ahb/apb/pinctrl@fffff200/spi0/spi0-0
./sys/firmware/devicetree/base/ahb/apb/pinctrl@fffff200/spi1
./sys/firmware/devicetree/base/ahb/apb/pinctrl@fffff200/spi1/spi1-0
./sys/firmware/devicetree/base/ahb/apb/spi@f0004000
./sys/firmware/devicetree/base/ahb/apb/spi@f8008000
./sys/firmware/devicetree/base/ahb/apb/spi@f8008000/m25p80@0/spi-max-frequency
./sys/kernel/debug/clk/spi0_clk
./sys/kernel/debug/clk/spi1_clk
./sys/module/spidev
./usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/slpspi.vim
./usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/slpspi.vim
./usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/spice.vim
./proc/irq/25/f0004000.spi
./proc/irq/30/f8008000.spi
```

Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: No way! In Device Tree enabled or any modern embedded board you have to properly create an SPI driver and register it either in Device Tree, or in ACPI. You code is trying to do what Linux core does already in generic way.

Comment: The Linux driver for the SPI master controller is a platform driver.  Therefore **/dev** does not have any device node for SPI master controller.  Study https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spi/spi-summary  You are using the wrong interface; you need a "SPI Protocol Driver" for your device.

Comment: Good to know! I have problems finding an example for an simple SPI protocol driver. How does the std. approach is? Like: 1st write driver(listing), 2nd add to kernel(copy where), 3rd modify device tree(insert at spi0: ....) und 4th build & deploy kernel

Comment: *"I have problems finding an example for an simple SPI protocol driver."* -- Search the kernel source for drivers that use `struct spi_driver`. SPI protocol drivers are located in directories describing their functionality.  If you're going to write kernel code, then you need to learn/use [kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle).

Comment: I was checking different sources, like https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/device-drivers/spi.html and https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spi/spi-summary. I did not find an tutorial which describes from the beginning to the end the process/code you need to hack to create an SPI protocol driver. Maybe there is an template or easy example in the kernel. For me there are alot of files and checking them for a simple example takes time.

Comment: *"For me there are alot of files and checking them for a simple example takes time"* -- Learn how to use `find` and `grep`, or use a Linux kernel cross-reference, e.g. http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=spi_driver.

Comment: Did you solve your problem yet ?

Comment: not in that way. The custom board uses shift registers, They work similar like an SPI device. I disabled the SPI in the dts and wrote a simple character device, toggling the pins.
@sawdust comment is right. For me as a module coder beginner it's difficult to find a good starting point(like an example) for coding a own SPI protocol.